# EJB, EntityManager, Persistence и с чем их едят

Tags: java

Доброго времени, товарищи!

История такая: есть задание (создать две сущности (Employee, Department), создать SessionBean(stateless) и парочка методов на добавление и удаление записей из таблиц(указан.сущностей)).

Предыстория: есть знания по JavaSE и "очень расплывчатые" - по JavaEE. на работе дали книжку (на англ. стр. на 700) и 3 дня. после дали указанное задание.
Сразу оговорка - к сожалению книги по программированию на англ. я никогда не читал. хотя уровень владения - Intermediate, но это мне не сильно помогло при судорожном чтении книги.
Товарищи с работы сказали, что норм литературы на русском по EJB нет.

У меня есть 2 дня (ночь и день), чтобы сделать задание (крайне надо).
Прошу помочь в указании вектора, что взять и почитать и понять (в сжатые сроки), чтобы сделать задание,а то щас просто сумбур в голове с этими EJB, Entry, Entrymanager, JPA, ORM и т.д.

Ооочень нужно короткое, понятное и ёмкое изложение темы!

Comment: Такое впечатление что на работе над Вами конкретно издеваются. Есть еще какие-то конкретные указания? Ну вроде апп сервер какой пользовать или еще что-нибудь?

Comment: Сходу нашлось в Я, http://wiki.linuxformat.ru/index.php/LXF99:Java_EE

Comment: Да, были. Сказали, что надо использовать jboss.
Может это проверка на прочность) 
Щас вроде вторую главу той волшебной книжки доканчиваю. Дошел до Persistence. В голове уже отрисовалась модель 3-х звенки. Вроде думается, что не все так сложно.
А за статейку спасибо большое. Но я вроде бы уже это у себя собрал в голове и даже чутка кода написал, похожего с идеей из статьи.
Занятны эти бины)

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть примеры из Apache TomEE https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/tomee-1.5.2/examples